# How to start my globally installed node application?

Tags: node.js, windows, git-bash

I developed small application.

I did this to install developed module globally:

```
npm install . -g
```

I got this response:

```
$ npm install -g .
update-deps-dev@1.0.0 C:\Users\Vladislav.Sharikov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\update-deps-dev
```

I got my module in place, where other globally installed modules are stored. Also, my module is available by:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

Now, I want to start this module from any place on my pc. How should I do this?

I try to run, but getting this:

```
Vladislav.Sharikov@PC /D/Dev
$ update-deps-dev
sh: update-deps-dev: command not found
```

I am using Windows 7 x64 + Git Bash.

How should I start *my* globally installed node application?

My `package.json` file contents:

```
{
  "name": "update-deps-dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you have not defined a bin field into the package file. Can you post it ?

Comment: Yes, it is not specified. I will post package.json soon. May be there is some article what and why node application (node package/node module) must have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about git bash. But in a cross platform way you can simply define a bin field on your package json to tell npm to generate a binary available on your command line later. It really works fine on windows, mac, linux.

Note that it is a per user binary. If you are working on linux it won t install it into `/usr/bin`, but depending on your system, more probably `~/node_modules/bin`.

Suppose your binary is defined into `bin.js` file, you just need to add a new Object field `bin`, and foreach bin you want to define a key, the name of the binary, and its value must point to the path of your bin file relative to the package file:

```
{
  "name": "update-deps-dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "update-deps-dev": "./bin.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

Read also,

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/bin